# Why is Bootstrap's col-xs-offset-* class working on other viewport sizes besides on extra small displays?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following html:

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8">
        ...
     </div>
 </div>
```

The problem is that I get a 1 column offset even when the view port is larger than 768px (the `xs` size). Any ideas why am I getting this offset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that's what you told it to do. As the Bootstrap [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-intro) say:

> Grid classes apply to devices with screen widths greater than or equal
>   to the breakpoint sizes, and override grid classes targeted at smaller
>   devices.

So you can override your `xs` offset with a `sm` one:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 col-xs-offset-1 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-0">
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I thought that `xs` classes apply only for view ports with size less than 768px.